# How to add categorised colours to leafmap polygons

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I have started using Leafmap and am having difficulty categorising colors into polygons based on unique 'SLOPE' values. I am able to build the map I want in Folium, and I want something similar in Leafmap, but I am not having great success. I cannot find any examples on GitHub.

Is there anyone familiar with Leafmap who knows how to add colors based on unique field values?

Folium Image   [image: Folium Map]

However, this is the map I am able to generate in Leafmap.

Leafmap Image[image].

This table is the query of data from the two images above
[image]
This is the code that generated the Leafmap image

```
import leafmap

Slope_Data = Slope_Data
m = leafmap.Map()

labels = ['0-1%', '1-10%', '10-20%', '> 20%']
colors = ['#169200', '#FFFF71', '#FFAA00', '#FF5500']
field=["SLOPE"],

m.add_legend(title='Legend', labels=labels, colors=colors)
#m.add_colormap(gdf, column="SLOPE", colors=colors,layer_name="SLOPE" )
m.add_gdf(Slope_Data,   colors=colors,layer_name="SLOPE" )
m
```

Answer (score 1):

The Leafmap API reference contains the foliumap module. Within the module, add_data() adds vector data to the map with a variety of classification schemes. https://leafmap.org/foliumap/#leafmap.foliumap.Map.add_data

The code below colors the 4 unique values in the "SLOPE" column.

```
import leafmap

Slope_Data = Slope_Data
m = leafmap.Map()

m.add_data(Slope_Data,
       layer_name = "SLOPE_DATA",
       categories=['0-1%', '1-10%', '10-20%','> 20%'], 
       colors=['#169200', '#FFFF71','#FFAA00', '#FF5500'], 
       column = "SLOPE", 
       #cmap="RdYlGn_r", 
       legend_position='bottomright',
       #style_kwds =dict(color="gray", LineWidth=10, weight=0.99)
        style = {
            "stroke": True,
            "color": "gray",
            "weight": .5,
            "opacity": .5,
            "fill": True,               
            "fillOpacity": 0.5,           
        }
      )
m
```

[image]